# convert a Windows VHD to a physical hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, disk2vhd

I have made a VHD from a laptop and now would like to copy the vhd back to the physical drive.I am trying to use this like Ghost would be used

Comment: Acronis True Home Image Plus supports the ability to convert it to a format that Acronis can restore to a physical hdd.

Answer (score 1):

I work on a windows deployment tool called, [SmartDeploy Enterprise](http://www.smartdeploy.com/Pagename.aspx?sid=DDAB137D-78CA-E011-A5C8-0050568C0003).  It allows you to deploy VHDs to physical hardware, which it sounds like you would like to do. We offer a 15 day trial too, so you can test out your situation above.